# How do I calculate the chord length I need to produce this Japanese sun pattern?

Tags: geometry, circles, arc-length

Japanese Sun Pattern

[image: Japanese Sun Pattern]

I want to draw a pattern as above with the circles overlapping. I have the diameter of the outer concentric circle. I want each sun pattern I draw to be equal in size - i.e. equal arc length for the outermost circle (white). Given a distance between each circles center both horizontally and vertically, how would I calculate the chord length to ensure I draw each arc equally (I am drawing on graph paper).

Comment: Chord length = $r$ and the vertical distance is $r$. I don't think you can choose the horizontal distance. Hope that helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the nested arcs to be concentric, you can choose centers so that they form a triangular lattice:

$\hspace{11.1em}$[image: Ginkgo-leaf pattern]

Then the arc length is $\frac{1}{3}$ of the full circle, which is simply $\frac{2\pi}{3} r$ where $r$ is the radius of the outermost circular arc. The following is an example created by this pattern:

$\hspace{5.5em}$[image: Wifi everywhere]

*Remark.* If you look closely at your pattern, nested arcs actually do not seem concentric. If you allow such feature, then there is an huge degree of freedom of mimicking them.

---

*p.s.* The *Mathematica 11* code I used to create the image:

[image]

Comment: Hi Sangchul, just curious, what did you use to create the second image?

Comment: @BenWest, I used Mathematica :) I included my code to my answer.

Comment: Nice job - Looks great!